# Magento 2 & PayPal Advanced Checkout - any solutions?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, payment-methods, paypal

I recently came across this PayPal Advanced Checkout solution:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/#link-howitworks

But I can't seem to find any information about how to integrate it with Magento 2.
I can't see that it integrates natively, so is there any extensions or how-to's that people can point me to about how to integrate PayPal Advanced Checkout to Magento 2.4?

Or maybe it isn't possible?

Thanks for the help